# How to determine whether Chromebook without wireless connectivity has a hardware or configuration issue?

Tags: wireless-networking, troubleshooting, chromebook

It's a Lenovo Flex 3 Chrome-11M836 - Type 82KM

Bluetooth is working, and Nearby Share works but only on inbound.

Here's the `network_diag` log output:

```
Trying to contact https://clients3.google.com ... (waiting up to 10 seconds)
Trying to contact http://clients3.google.com ... (waiting up to 10 seconds)
Trying to contact https://clients3.google.com ... (waiting up to 10 seconds)
FAIL: Got DNS resolution error -- trying to debug nameservers
### Entering diag_nameservers
FAIL: No nameservers -- this is either a network failure or net misconfig
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Feb 15 21:43 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/shill/resolv.conf
FAIL: /run/shill/resolv.conf does not exist
### Entering diag_ifall
### Entering diag_if arc_ns0
arc_ns0: flags=67<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.115.92.129  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast 100.115.92.131
        inet6 fe80::3c83:e1ff:fe7e:cbf0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3e:83:e1:7e:cb:f0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 22  bytes 1672 (1.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 61  bytes 5100 (4.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

FAIL: arc_ns0 is not listed as up
FAIL: arc_ns0 is not assigned an IP address
### Entering diag_link arc_ns0
PASS: arc_ns0: link detected
### Entering diag_link_wired arc_ns0
Output from ethtool arc_ns0:
Last 10 kernel messages for arc_ns0:
2023-02-20T21:54:57.421623Z INFO kernel: [   13.216027] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): arc_ns0: link becomes ready
2023-02-20T21:59:48.078767Z INFO kernel: [   11.872667] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): arc_ns0: link becomes ready
2023-02-18T09:50:41.568262Z INFO kernel: [   12.769141] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): arc_ns0: link becomes ready
2023-02-23T10:34:44.527743Z INFO kernel: [   12.319553] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): arc_ns0: link becomes ready
2023-02-23T11:22:12.118827Z INFO kernel: [   10.912584] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): arc_ns0: link becomes ready
### Entering diag_if arc_ns1
arc_ns1: flags=67<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.115.92.133  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast 100.115.92.135
        inet6 fe80::ca6:caff:fe3b:a544  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7e:ac:ab:29:d9:e8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 22  bytes 1672 (1.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62  bytes 5210 (5.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

FAIL: arc_ns1 is not listed as up
FAIL: arc_ns1 is not assigned an IP address
### Entering diag_link arc_ns1
PASS: arc_ns1: link detected
### Entering diag_link_wired arc_ns1
Output from ethtool arc_ns1:
Last 10 kernel messages for arc_ns1:
### Entering diag_if arcbr0
arcbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.115.92.1  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast 100.115.92.3
        inet6 fe80::70be:48ff:fe6b:b824  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9e:ed:fc:74:82:35  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20  bytes 1196 (1.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 41  bytes 3510 (3.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

FAIL: arcbr0 is not listed as up
FAIL: arcbr0 is not assigned an IP address
### Entering diag_link arcbr0
PASS: arcbr0: link detected
### Entering diag_link_wired arcbr0
Output from ethtool arcbr0:
Last 10 kernel messages for arcbr0:
2023-02-23T11:22:28.626732Z INFO kernel: [   27.420522] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered blocking state
2023-02-23T11:22:28.626809Z INFO kernel: [   27.420549] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered disabled state
2023-02-23T11:22:28.626883Z INFO kernel: [   27.420999] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered blocking state
2023-02-23T11:22:28.626903Z INFO kernel: [   27.421009] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered forwarding state
2023-02-23T11:28:53.955974Z INFO kernel: [  412.750023] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered disabled state
2023-02-23T11:28:53.957053Z INFO kernel: [  412.750795] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered disabled state
2023-02-23T11:29:02.854962Z INFO kernel: [  421.648712] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered blocking state
2023-02-23T11:29:02.855012Z INFO kernel: [  421.648736] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered disabled state
2023-02-23T11:29:02.855026Z INFO kernel: [  421.649314] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered blocking state
2023-02-23T11:29:02.855033Z INFO kernel: [  421.649323] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered forwarding state
### Entering diag_if vetharc0
vetharc0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::9ced:fcff:fe74:8235  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9e:ed:fc:74:82:35  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21  bytes 1566 (1.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 48  bytes 4256 (4.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

FAIL: vetharc0 is not listed as up
FAIL: vetharc0 is not assigned an IP address
### Entering diag_link vetharc0
PASS: vetharc0: link detected
### Entering diag_link_wired vetharc0
Output from ethtool vetharc0:
Last 10 kernel messages for vetharc0:
2023-02-23T11:22:28.626903Z INFO kernel: [   27.421009] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered forwarding state
2023-02-23T11:28:53.955974Z INFO kernel: [  412.750023] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered disabled state
2023-02-23T11:28:53.956953Z INFO kernel: [  412.750778] device vetharc0 left promiscuous mode
2023-02-23T11:28:53.957053Z INFO kernel: [  412.750795] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered disabled state
2023-02-23T11:29:02.838713Z INFO kernel: [  421.632648] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vetharc0: link becomes ready
2023-02-23T11:29:02.854962Z INFO kernel: [  421.648712] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered blocking state
2023-02-23T11:29:02.855012Z INFO kernel: [  421.648736] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered disabled state
2023-02-23T11:29:02.855020Z INFO kernel: [  421.649060] device vetharc0 entered promiscuous mode
2023-02-23T11:29:02.855026Z INFO kernel: [  421.649314] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered blocking state
2023-02-23T11:29:02.855033Z INFO kernel: [  421.649323] arcbr0: port 1(vetharc0) entered forwarding state
### Entering diag_if vmtap0
vmtap0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.115.92.25  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast 100.115.92.27
        inet6 fe80::fca1:30ff:fe30:24d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:a1:30:30:02:4d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 153  bytes 12809 (12.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 90  bytes 8156 (7.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

FAIL: vmtap0 is not listed as up
FAIL: vmtap0 is not assigned an IP address
### Entering diag_link vmtap0
PASS: vmtap0: link detected
### Entering diag_link_wired vmtap0
Output from ethtool vmtap0:
Last 10 kernel messages for vmtap0:
FAIL: No good interfaces found.  You are not connected to a network.
PASS: shill is running, pid 1401
PASS: wpa_supplicant is running, pid 1007
### Entering get_device_list
Device list:
arc_ns0 unknown::   
arc_ns1 unknown::   
arcbr0  unknown::   
vetharc0    unknown::   
vmtap0  unknown::   
### Entering diag_flimflam
PASS: shill is running, pid 1401
Listing of /run/shill
total 4
drwxr-xr-x.  3 shill shill   80 Feb 23 16:48 .
drwxr-xr-x. 60 root  root  1360 Feb 23 16:52 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 shill shill   56 Feb 23 16:48 loaded_profile_list
drwx------.  2 shill shill   60 Feb 23 16:48 user_profiles
### Entering diag_flimflam_dbus
Flimflam Manager:
/0/ActiveProfile /profile/chronos/shill
/1/AlwaysOnVpnPackage 
/2/ArpGateway true
/4/CheckPortalList ethernet,wifi,cellular
/7/ConnectionState idle
/8/DHCPProperty.Hostname HC-CB
/10/DefaultService /
/11/DefaultTechnology 
/13/DisableWiFiVHT false
/15/IgnoredDNSSearchPaths gateway.2wire.net
/17/NoAutoConnectTechnologies 
/18/PortalFallbackHttpUrls http://safebrowsing.google.com/generate_204,http://www.googleapis.com/generate_204,http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204
/19/PortalFallbackHttpsUrls https://www.gstatic.com/generate_204,https://accounts.google.com/generate_204,https://www.googleapis.com/generate_204
/20/PortalHttpUrl http://www.gstatic.com/generate_204
/21/PortalHttpsUrl https://www.google.com/generate_204
/22/Profiles/0 /profile/default
/22/Profiles/1 /profile/chronos/shill
/23/ProhibitedTechnologies 
/24/ServiceCompleteList/0 /service/2
/24/ServiceCompleteList/1 /service/5
/24/ServiceCompleteList/2 /service/13
/24/ServiceCompleteList/3 /service/7
/24/ServiceCompleteList/4 /service/16
/24/ServiceCompleteList/5 /service/21
/24/ServiceCompleteList/6 /service/22
/24/ServiceCompleteList/7 /service/26
/24/ServiceCompleteList/8 /service/27
/24/ServiceCompleteList/9 /service/4
/24/ServiceCompleteList/10 /service/6
/24/ServiceCompleteList/11 /service/9
/24/ServiceCompleteList/12 /service/10
/24/ServiceCompleteList/13 /service/11
/24/ServiceCompleteList/14 /service/12
/24/ServiceCompleteList/15 /service/15
/24/ServiceCompleteList/16 /service/17
/24/ServiceCompleteList/17 /service/18
/24/ServiceCompleteList/18 /service/19
/24/ServiceCompleteList/19 /service/20
/24/ServiceCompleteList/20 /service/23
/24/ServiceCompleteList/21 /service/24
/24/ServiceCompleteList/22 /service/25
/24/ServiceCompleteList/23 /service/28
/24/ServiceCompleteList/24 /service/8
/24/ServiceCompleteList/25 /service/14
/24/ServiceCompleteList/26 /service/0
/24/ServiceCompleteList/27 /service/1
/24/ServiceCompleteList/28 /service/3
/27/State offline
/28/SupportedVPNTypes l2tpipsec,openvpn,thirdpartyvpn,arcvpn,ikev2,wireguard
/29/TetheringAllowed false
/30/TetheringCapabilities/1/upstream_technologies/0 ethernet
/30/TetheringCapabilities/1/upstream_technologies/1 cellular
/31/TetheringConfig/0/auto_disable true
/31/TetheringConfig/1/band all-bands
/31/TetheringConfig/2/passphrase 403F07B9
/31/TetheringConfig/3/randomize_mac_address true
/31/TetheringConfig/4/security wpa2
/31/TetheringConfig/5/ssid 6368726F6D654F532D36393131
/31/TetheringConfig/6/upstream_technology cellular
/32/TetheringStatus/0/state idle
/34/WakeOnLanEnabled true
/35/WiFi.GlobalFTEnabled true
/36/WiFi.ScanAllowRoam true
### Entering diag_date clients3.google.com 
Local time of day: Sat Feb 25 04:20:26 PST 2023
FAIL: Unable to get date via tlsdate from clients3.google.com: V: tlsdate version 0.0.5
V: We were called with the following arguments:
V: validate SSL certificates host = clients3.google.com:443
V: time is currently 1677327626.936919470
V: time is greater than RECENT_COMPILE_DATE
V: using TLSv1_2_client_method()
V: setting up connection to clients3.google.com:443
getaddrinfo (clients3.google.com): Temporary failure in name resolution
child process failed in SSL handshake
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for all cases, but for mine specifically it ended up being a hardware issue; I tore it down, cleaned everything with isopropyl 99%, then reassembled and it started to function again.